# Loop until connected to server with BeginConnect (C# sockets)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, client

I need a method that attempts to connect to the server until it successfully connects. I've done so successfully with Socket.Connect but I can't get it to work with Socket.BeginConnect.

This is the method:

```
public void Start()
{
    while (clientSocket == null || !clientSocket.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            clientSocket.BeginConnect(serverEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            clientSocket.Close();
            Start();
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; } 
    }
}

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
    }
    catch (Exception) { throw; }
}
```

But I get this error (multiple times):

> System.ArgumentException: The IAsyncResult object was not returned
>   from the corresponding asynchronous method on this class. Parameter
>   name: asyncResult at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   SocketLibrary.Client.TCPClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectCallback() at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.RegisteredWaitCallback(Object state, Boolean
>   timedOut) at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object
>   state, Boolean timedOut)

I tried catching the ArgumentException but then I got this error (multiple times again)

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. at
>   SocketLibrary.Client.TCPClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectCallback() at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.RegisteredWaitCallback(Object state, Boolean
>   timedOut) at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object
>   state, Boolean timedOut)

I'm fairly new to working with sockets (and I've only been programming for a couple of months) so I'm sure I'm going about this entirely wrong so I'd appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: It's most likely something with connection to server. Try to ping it or use telnet to see if you can reach it. Most likely `clientSocket` send request via sockets and awaits response but never gets one hence the exception is thrown

Comment: The server has worked fine with every other test, only when I try to connect in this manner does it happen. However, the server does say that the client is connecting like 10 times and then disconnecting immediately afterward.
Edit: Also, it works with telnet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted complete code, I am assuming you are trying to use global `client` object. In the `ConnectCallback`, you need to first retrieve and typecast the `client` object into a `Socket`. So in your case, it would be:

```
private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{  
    try 
    {  
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
        client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        //In case, you are using local client object
        //Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.  
        client.EndConnect(ar);  

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",  
            client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());  

        // Signal that the connection has been made.  
        connectDone.Set();  
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
    }  
}
```

The above code is taken from [this MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) example, have a look at it. If you fix, the first step in your approach, it should work.